# How do I exit the click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So with this example I have form with a hidden field and a button called ban user. When the ban user button is clicked, it submits the value in the hidden field and sends the ajax request to a java servlet. If it is successful, the user is banned and the button is changed to "unban user". The problem is when I click the button once and ban a user and I try to click it again to unban, I'm still inside the click event for the ban user and I get the alert "Are you sure you want to ban the user with the id of ...?". How do I exit the click event to make sure when the button is clicked a second time, it starts at the beginning of the function and not inside the click function? I have tried using 'return;' as you can see below but that doesn't work.

```
$(document).delegate('form', 'click', function() {
var $form = $(this);
var id = $form.attr('id');
var formIdTrim = id.substring(0,7);
if(formIdTrim === "banUser") {
     $(id).submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     });

     var trimmed = id.substring(7);
     var dataString = $form.serialize();
     var userID = null;
     userID = $("input#ban"+ trimmed).val();

     $("#banButton"+ trimmed).click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         //get the form data and then serialize that


         dataString = "userID=" + userID;

         // do the extra stuff here
         if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ban the user with the id of ' + trimmed +'?')) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "UserBan",
                 data: dataString,
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data) {
                     if (data.success) {
                        //$("#banUser"+trimmed).html("");
                        $('#banUser'+trimmed).attr('id','unbanUser'+trimmed);
                        $('#ban'+trimmed).attr('id','unban'+trimmed);
                        $('#banButton'+trimmed).attr('value',' UnBan User ');
                        $('#banButton'+trimmed).attr('name','unbanButton'+trimmed);
                        $('#banButton'+trimmed).attr('id','unbanButton'+trimmed);
                        $form = null;
                        id = null;
                        formIdTrim = null;
                        return;
                      }else {
                         alert("Error");
                      }


                }
             });
         } else {

         }
     });
} 
else if(formIdTrim === "unbanUs") {

    //Stops the submit request
    $(id).submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });

    var trimmed = id.substring(9);
    var dataString = $form.serialize();
    var userID = null;
    userID = $("input#unban"+ trimmed).val();

    $("#unbanButton"+ trimmed).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //get the form data and then serialize that


        dataString = "userID=" + userID;

        // do the extra stuff here
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to UNBAN the user with the id of ' + trimmed +'?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UserUnban",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        //$("#banUser"+trimmed).html("");
                        $('#unbanUser'+trimmed).attr('id','banUser'+trimmed);
                        $('#unban'+trimmed).attr('id','ban'+trimmed);
                        $('#unbanButton'+trimmed).attr('value',' Ban User ');
                        $('#unbanButton'+trimmed).attr('name','banButton'+trimmed);
                        $('#unbanButton'+trimmed).attr('id','banButton'+trimmed);
                        $form = null;
                        id = null;
                        formIdTrim = null;
                        return;
                     }else {
                         alert("Error");
                     }


                }
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
}


});
```

Comment: This code is very confuse. Try to set a class on the button like 'banned' and 'ban', and when the user click on button, you change the class and do what you wanna do

Comment: You can put your html, javascript code in JsFiddle.net... and then we can take a look at it. Without looking at how you have your setup, It is quite difficult to find the solution you are expecting. In addition, I feel like there is a type, but I could be wrong. Shouldnt it be ... else if(formIdTrim === "unbanUser")

Comment: I'll put it on jsfiddle now but it won't run or anything because of the ajax. With regards the formIdTrim else if(formIdTrim === "unbanUs"), this is correct because when I declare formIdTrim I use var formIdTrim = id.substring(0,7);. unbanUs is the first 7 letters for it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zwhnkpwm/ here it is

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

$("#banButton"+ trimmed).off('click').on('click', (function(e){......

I had similar problem and this was solution

Comment: That's close but when I click it a second time the wrong alert comes up but when I click cancel on the alert and click the ban button again, the right alert comes up. Does that make sense what I said?